# How to Handle the Hashtable null value?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem while checking a hashtable value. In the code below I am storing 60 values in the hashtable "hash". One of the values is (or can be) Null. I am checking each entry against its corresponding entry in hashtable "hash1", to see if they match each other. If they don't match I want to check if the value in "hash" is Null, but I can't catch it - it's falling through the 'else' part). How can I overcome this problem?

```
if (hash[j].ToString() == "")
{
    NotAnswerQuestionCount++;
}
```

**My Code:**

```
int ctAnsCount=0, flAnsCount=0,NotAnswerQuestionCount=0;
SqlDataAdapter sda = 
    new SqlDataAdapter("select quesno,[Key] from Answerkey" ,con);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
sda.Fill(ds);

Hashtable hash = new Hashtable();

for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++)
{
    hash[i+1] = ResultsListBox.Items[i].ToString();
}

Hashtable hash1 = new Hashtable();

for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++)
{
    hash1[i+1] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][1].ToString();
}

for (int j = 1; j <=60; j++)
{
    if (hash[j].ToString() != hash1[j].ToString())
    {
        if (hash[j].ToString() == "")
        {
            NotAnswerQuestionCount++;
        }
        //else


        flAnsCount++;
    }
    else
    {           
        ctAnsCount++;    
    }
}
```

Comment: I got solution above issue if(hash[j].ToString() == " ") , here was the problem is we need to mention one blank space  in between Qutos..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you mean null, I think you mean empty. You're checking the contents of 'hash', which looks like it is filled from a ListBox, but AFAIK a ListBox item can't be null. Also, you're checking to see if it matches the empty string (`""`).

How do you know that you have an empty string in the ListBox? Try Trim-ing the value before you check it (i.e. `if (hash[j].ToString().Trim() == "")` to catch empty strings as well as strings that only contain whitespace. Alternatively output the contents of each ListBox item to debug, bracketed by a delimiter, to check that you've actually got, like so:

```
foreach (Object o in ResultsListBox.Items) {
  Debug.WriteLine("'" + o.ToString() + "'");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Test for hash1[i] != null prior to using ToString().

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(hash1[i]))` or check for null prior to calling `ToString()`.

```
if (hash[i] != null &&
    hash[i].ToString() == "")
    {
      ...
```

Answer (score 0):

From C# 6 and onwards you can use the [Null-conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx) `?.`

```
if (hash[i]?.ToString() == "") { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check whether a Hash Object is null or size is zero.

I think you can do like this

```
if (hash!= null || hash.Keys.Count==0) { blah }
```

Thank you.